# Do vowels have a natural pitch?

Tags: pronunciation, vowels

I cannot help but perceive the [i:] in *be* as "lighter" (higher in pitch) than the [æ] in *cat*.
*Boot* sounds even lower (when not altering the pitch intentionally).

Is that self-persuasion or could a more closed mouth (or tongue) position lead to a higher pitch?

Comment: I think this is just "self-persuasion". Singers and lyricists would have real problems if they had to allow for any such effect.

Comment: [linguistics.se]

Comment: @Kris Yeah right, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Different vowels certainly have very different mixtures of overtones/formants. It's possible that this is what you're responding to. "Pitch", however, refers to the fundamental tone.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is self-persuasion. Personally, I think it is a narration property that is a positive attribute.  Personally, monotone narration seems less desirable regardless of the content.